# Least squares problem with left and right unknowns

Tags: st.statistics, eigenvector, least-squares, linear-regression

For $i=1,...,n$, let $b_i$ be a scalar and $A_i$ be an $k\times l$ matrix. Is there a closed form solution for the following problem assuming $n>k+l$?
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^k ,y\in \mathbb{R}^l} \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-x' A_i y)^2$$

Comment: Taking the derivative of that sum with respect to a coordinate of $x$ gives something linear in the $x$’s and quadratic in the $y$’s — so zeroing out all the derivatives for a closed-form solution would require solving $k+l$ simultaneous cubics, which is not going to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a closed-form solution will be forthcoming (since it's a nonlinear least squares problem). As an alternative, you could try a numerical solution.

For example, this Mathematica code gives a quick answer (I tried it on 100 random matrices of size 30x60).

```
k=30;l=60;n=100;
a=Table[RandomReal[],{i,1,k},{j,1,l},{p,1,n}];b=Table[RandomReal[],{i,1,n}];
xx=Array[x,k];yy=Array[y,l];zz=Flatten[{xx,yy}];
f[zz_]:=Sum[(b[[p]]-Sum[a[[i,j,p]]*xx[[i]]*yy[[j]],{i,1,k},{j,1,l}])^2,{p,1,n}]
NMinimize[f[zz],zz]
```

Prompted by Fedja's comment I experimented a bit. Mathematica offers a variety of [numerical nonlinear global optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html) methods. For a large number of variables (as in the example above), I found the [Nelder-Mead method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) and the [simulated annealing method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) to be most efficient. Both use random numbers to search for the global minimum, so one strategy to see how well they are doing is to run each multiple times with different random number seeds, and compare the minima.

My limited experience is that the same minimum does show up repeatedly, giving some confidence that it is a global minimum.

```
Do[Print[NMinimize[f[zz],zz,Method->{"SimulatedAnnealing","PerturbationScale"->7,"RandomSeed"->i}]], {i,5}]        
Do[Print[NMinimize[f[zz],zz,Method->{"NelderMead","ShrinkRatio"->0.85,"ContractRatio"->0.85,"ReflectRatio"->2,"RandomSeed"->i}]], {i,5}]
```

Comment: Knowing Matematica's behavior and how good it is in general when it really matters, I would rather try it on one matrix for which one does know the answer and it is not obvious :lol:

Comment: @fedja -- thanks for the feedback; I experimented a bit, comparing the various methods Mathematica offers.